# Elixir: required inside a macro

Tags: elixir

I wrote a macro, and I want to use Logger.info in it, so i have to require Logger. What is the best practice to do this? Oblige the client to require Logger on its own, or add using macro and require Logger there.

Comment: Great question - I'm actually doing pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice would be *not to log from your macros* all of a sudden. As a user of your macro, I might do not want to have my log polluted with irrelevant information. On the other hand, that might be a significant to have such an ability opt-in. That said, I would go with a parametrized  `__using__`:

```
defmodule My do
  defmacro __using__(opts \\ [log: false]) do
    quote do
      if unquote(opts)[:log], do: require Logger

      defmacro my_log(what) do
        if unquote(opts)[:log] do
          Logger.info(what)
        end 
      end

      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can safely call `my_log` when needed and if the user did not explicitly require the ability to log via params passed to `use`:

```
use My, log: true
```

*no single trace* of `Logger` will pollute the resulting code.

Comment: I'm finding that this causes a compile error when I try to use it: `** (CompileError) iex:2: you must require Logger before invoking the macro Logger.info/1`. If I just require Logger without the conditional, it works perfectly. Does the code work for you, as is? I'm using Elixir 1.6.5.

Comment: @skwidbreth yes, you’re right, it does not work as expected; I am unable to discover the reason at a glance, I will try to understand what’s happening during the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Logger call need to be inside the macro? Perhaps the macro can expand to a function call to a module that then does the logging.

If it is really necessary to perform the logging from the macro expansion, then I'd add a `__using__` macro to require dependencies and your module.

Comment: Expanding any `Logger` operation to a call to a function is a very bad idea in a nutshell, since it ruins the idea of [compilation time purging](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-application-configuration).